# TotalSizeCap is not honored in logback 1.1.7

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback

I am trying to reduce the disk size by limiting the log file. Here is my logback appender.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/tmp/foo/log/log.out</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/tmp/foo/log/log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.out</fileNamePattern>
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

**Error**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@18:27 - no applicable action for [totalSizeCap], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][totalSizeCap]]
    at

Comment: Are you sure you do not have conflicted versions. Make sure you use 1.1.7

Comment: @ benjamin.d I am very sure, I am using logback of version 1.1.7 and there is no version conflicts.